# Whether options menu at the bottom in Android can be made permanent?

Tags: android, menu

Whether options menu at the bottom (Inflated menu) can be made permanent? The menu should be permanently inflated without the need for user to press the menu button?

whether it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> whether it can be done?

No.

Besides, that menu is going away. Honeycomb and Ice Cream Sandwich are moving to the action bar pattern, where the options menu is integrated into the action bar as a drop-down menu and optional toolbar buttons.

If you want to give the user some always-visible set of actions, consider adding the action bar to your own applications. You can do this on pre-Honeycomb devices using third-party action bar implementations like ActionBarSherlock.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your layout in a relativelayout and add buttons to the bottom. You can have it look similar too.

Answer (score 1):

As Bill said you can add buttons in Relative layout and not create menu...if you need some code just tell me...

Comment: Adding buttons is okay the problem is for different screens I have to create different layouts! So there is no way inflated menu can be made permanent at the bottom? :(

Comment: From my experiance I did'n find a way to do that...but i thought of something: maybe try this:

Comment: But i thought of something: maybe try this:
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.root); (declare your root layout)
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, l);
Try this, but i think that cant work..i'm not sure..and don't have time right now to check... Tell me if you have any luck!! :)

Answer (score 1):

In which version you want the solution , 
in tab versions and 4.0 you can solve this problem as follows.

in manifest file add this attibute to application Tag android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" so that your actionbar shows in the bottom. while your mobile is in portrait , in landscape it shows as usual on the top

and them add this flag to your menu item
MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS

check this link for more flags http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html i hope this will solve the issue